# Is the set of all choice sets on a infinite partition on $\mathbb N$ equal in cardinality to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal S=\{\{2n,2n+1\} |\ n \in \mathbb N\}$

Define: $X \text{ is a choice set on } \mathcal S \iff X \subset \mathbb N \wedge   \forall s \in \mathcal S \exists! x \in X (x \in s)$

Define $\mathcal P^c(\mathcal S)=\{X| \ X \text{ is a choice set on } \mathcal S \}$

Does $\text{ZF}$ prove: $\mathcal |P^c(\mathcal S)| = |\mathcal P(\mathbb N)| $?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Consider the map $F:\mathcal{P}^c(\mathcal{S})\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ sending a choice set $X$ to the set $$F(X)=\{n: 2n\in X\}.$$ It's easy to check that this is a bijection, and *vastly* less than ZF is required.

---

Similarly, ZF proves that if $\mathcal{S}$ is any partition of $\mathbb{N}$ into infinitely many pieces, infinitely many of which has more than one element, then $\vert\mathcal{P}^c(\mathcal{S})\vert=\vert\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\vert.$ *Conversely, it's clear that if $\mathcal{S}$ has only finitely many pieces with more than one element then $\mathcal{P}^c(\mathcal{S})$ is countable, so this is optimal.*

To see this, first note that we can assume WLOG that in fact every piece in $\mathcal{S}$ has more than one element (just throw out the pieces with one element). Enumerate the elements of $\mathcal{S}$ as $(S_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, let $a_i$ be the least element of $S_i$, and let $b_i$ be the second least element of $S_i$. Now consider the map $F:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\mathcal{P}^c(\mathcal{S})$ given by $$F(A)=\{a_i: i\in A\}\cup\{b_i: i\not\in A\}.$$ This is clearly an injection, and since the inclusion map $\mathcal{P}^c(\mathcal{S})\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ gives an injection in the other direction, we get a bijection from Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein (which **does not** require choice). And again, even ZF is massive overkill.

Comment: @Zuhair I literally gave a bijection between the two ...

Comment: Correct, thank you!